# How to iterate emails in a outlook folder and put it in a csv file per email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, win32com

I have a folder that I want to iterate through the emails and save the metadata per email to a csv file.

I want the csv output to look like:

```
emailSubject, sender,   senderEmailAddress
<subject>,    <sender>,       <senderEmailAddress>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import win32com.client

# Input
results = {}
f = open("testfile.txt", "w+")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Test Folder")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items

# Process
for x in msg:
    senderEmail = x.SenderEmailAddress
    sender = x.Sender
    subject = x.Subject
```

I am new to python and am having troubles adding the section of code to add each element to a csv file. Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the rest of your code works to your satisfaction, you can use the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) to write your desired file.

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Test Folder")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items

f = open("testfile.txt", "w", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(["emailSubject", "sender", "senderEmailAddress"])

# Process
for x in msg:
    senderEmail = x.SenderEmailAddress
    sender = x.Sender
    subject = x.Subject
    writer.writerow([subject, sender, senderEmail])

f.close()
```